# How to find a number into a string from a string using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this string `"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"` and I want to know if any number is in a table of database.

Example

**Entity**

```
public class MyNumber {
     public string Numbers {get;set;}
}

MyNumber n = new MyNumber();
n.Numbers = "1,2,3,4,";

MyNumber n1 = new MyNumber();
n.Numbers = "5,6,7,8,9,10,"

context.MyNumbers.Add(n, n1);
context.SaveChanges();

//find numbers from a string of numbers
string _numbers = "10,11,12,15,"

//how to ?
var _myNum = context.MyNumbers.Where
.Select(x => x.Split(new string[]{","},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
.Where(x => _numbers.Split(new string[]{","},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
.Any(y => y.Equals(x)));

 //no results
 Debug.Writeline(_myNum.Count());
```

The string "_numbers" has the number 10 for example, and in database has the number "10", I would to know how could I find it using LINQ ?

Comment: Where(n => n.Numbers.Contains("10,"))  making sure to include the comma so it doesn't match numbers like 100, 101, etc..

Comment: @hijinxbassist I would like to know how could I do it using the string `string _numbers = "10,11,12,15,"` directly and it will find 10 because had 10 in n1. Could you understand ?`

Comment: You would need to split the string, and check for each individual number unless you wanted to match the exact string.  You could also write a stored procedure to do the heavy lifting on the sql side.

Comment: Something like `context.MyNumbers.Select(x => x.Split(new string[]{","},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Where(x => _numbers.Split(new string[]{","},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Any(y => y == x))`

Comment: just a thought: isn't a comma separated string a _terrible_ choice to store a `List` of `Integers`?

Comment: @Hayden I am trying your suggestion but it does not works throwing an exception `Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in EntityFramework.dll`. Could you help me ?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us exactly what you tried so that we can assist you better.

Comment: @Hayden I've edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to store multiple values as a single comma-separated value in a database column. [Read More.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Either way, the problem with your approach is that Linq to SQL does not support `String.Split`. You can still use Linq to Objects by calling `AsEnumerable()` on your `DbSet`. Then you can use any Linq technique you prefer.

An example:

```
var _myNum = context.MyNumbers
    .AsEnumerable()
    .SelectMany(x => x.Numbers.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Intersect(_numbers.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .ToArray();
```